# Difference between FPDFAnnot_SetRect and FPDFAnnot_AppendAttachmentPoints when adding a annotation to pdf document

Tags: pdf-generation, adobe, pdfium, pdf-annotations

I'm using pdfium to add annotations to pdf files. 
I opened the pdf file using Notepad++ and viewed its objects. Annotation object was present inside the Page object as follows,

```
3 0 obj
<</Annots[<</C[ 1 1 0]/CA 1/F 4/QuadPoints[ 0 300 300 300 0 0 300 0]/Rect[ 216.182 702.94 368.75 686.38]/Subtype/Highlight/Type/Annot>>]/Contents 4 0 R /Group<</CS/DeviceRGB/S/Transparency/Type/Group>>/MediaBox[ 0 0 612 792]/Parent 2 0 R /Resources<</ExtGState<</GS7 7 0 R /GS8 8 0 R >>/Font<</F1 5 0 R >>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI]>>/StructParents 0/Tabs/S/Type/Page>>
endobj
```

I used following code to add the rect and attachment points to the annotation.

```
FPDF_ANNOTATION highlightAnnot = FPDFPage_CreateAnnot(page, FPDF_ANNOT_HIGHLIGHT);
FPDFAnnot_SetRect(highlightAnnot, &rect);
FPDFAnnot_AppendAttachmentPoints(highlightAnnot, &new_quadpoints);
```

As I understood, Attachment points are set to give the location of Highlight annotation where we want it to be. But I don't understand the purpose of setting the Rect for this annotation.

**Can someone please tell the reason for using FPDFAnnot_SetRect function?**

Another thing,

Comment: Removed PostScript tag; nothing to do with PostScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FPDFAnnot_SetRect defines the bounding box, while FPDFAnnot_AppendAttachmentPoints defines the actual shape. Consider a **multiline** highlight annotation, it has only one `Rect`, but several `AttachmentPoints`.

A `Rect` could be used as a "collision box" at application level so that when you click on it, you select the contained annotation. Or it can be an "updating box".

`Rect` is more general and only text-related annotation types have `AttachmentPoints`.